# How to generate a non-repetitive sequence of random numbers using std::rand

Tags: c++, c++11, random

Reading [std::uniform_int_distribution](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/uniform_int_distribution) in the final example the generated sequence is:

```
1 1 6 5 2 2 5 5 6 2
```

How can I guarantee that all the generated numbers are different between them? And if this is possible, what is the expected behavior if we generate more numbers than the ranger size?

I need this because I have to randomly select a small number of rows (say 10) in a `cv::Mat` with hundreds of thousands (even millions) of rows.

Comment: Yes it can happen. Also, obligatory: http://dilbert.com/strip/2001-10-25

Comment: If all numbers were different, they wouldn't be uniform now, would they.

Comment: Unlike real numbers, there are only a finite number of `double`s...

Comment: Please notice that I changed a little bit the original question

Comment: @KerrekSB well you're right, but a simple solution could be to pick up again a number if already generated.

Comment: "If all numbers were different, they wouldn't be uniform now, would they." I'll be thinking about that all weekend now.

Comment: I did until @KerrekSB mentioned that. My wife is out this evening. Armed with a nice claret I will set about writing a proof.

Comment: Hope it's not a moving target like this question.... (I mean to proof, not your wife).

Comment: @Bathsheba: Well, it's not too hard to see: Once you have seen one number, you would now have knowledge that that number cannot appear, which is not compatible with each number having the same, fixed probability of appearing.

Comment: Yeah but I want to go further back than that.

Comment: @justHelloWorld: Your question isn't answerable in general. For example, there is no way to generate a sequence with the properties you ask for that is longer than the number of representable values of the type.

Comment: What exactly do you intend to do with these not-so-random numbers?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Of course. For a *true* generator, the probably of getting a number is not dependent on any previous numbers. And pseudo random number generators attempt to simulate this property remarkably well.

If you want to generate numbers without duplicates then your best bet is to base a solution around `std::shuffle`: i.e. define the numbers you want, then shuffle them.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, `std::shuffle` is definitely a good idea. What if I have a range of millions of elements? Creating and shuffling a vector (like [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/random_shuffle) ) could be very memory and time expensive, don't you think?

Comment: You might get away with a 1d Sobol sequence.

Comment: A sobol sequence is a good approximation to a uniform distribution and will not draw a duplicate mathematically speaking. You might be able to shuffle sections of its output.

Answer (score 0):

> I need this because I have to randomly select a small number of rows (say 10) in a `cv::Mat` with hundreds of thousands (even millions) of rows.

```
template<class Generator>
std::vector<std::size_t> pick_some( std::size_t count, std::size_t max, Generator& g ) {
  ASSERT(count*2 < max); // massively slow if count is close to max
  if (count > max) throw std::out_of_range("count");
  ASSERT(count < 1000); // O(n^2) implementation, slow for large count
  std::vector<std::size_t> selected;
  uniform_int_distribution<std::size_t> distribution(0,max);
  while (selected.size() < count) {
    auto v = distribution(g);
    if (std::find( begin(selected), end(selected), v ) != end(selected))
      continue;
    selected.push_back(v);
  }
  return selected;
}
```

This assumes max pretty large compared to count, and count is small.

For larger count, you can replace `selected` with a `std::unordered_set` or somesuch (which removes the linear find).

For small count, linear find will be faster.

As count approaches max, you can find the elements to *not* select instead.  Then invert.

But both of those are outside your problem domain, so I just put in ASSERTs.

Comment: So if I understand you correctly, you just randomly pick a number and if it was already chosen you simply discard it. In my problem `count` is between 10 and 50, but `max` is highly variable. Just to make you understand, in some very uncommon case (1 over 5k) we have that `count>max` and I have to pick all the rows. It's kinda unpredictable, since the matrix rows is the number of "interesting points" in image (according to the [SIFT](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/da/df5/tutorial_py_sift_intro.html) algorithm).

Comment: @justHelloWorld Your question stated you wanted a solution for selecting a small number of rows from 100s of thousands or millions or rows.  Your comment states that your question wasn't what you meant to ask.  If you have a new question that isn't what you asked above, feel free to click the "Ask a Question" button above and I'm sure someone will solve that one as well.  Or you could use the comments in my answer where I anticipated your problem and sketched how to solve those cases.